# Is there any sql query to rename attribute code

Tags: attributes, database, sql

we have lot of attribute codes that need to be renamed.

if we use eav_attribute table and if we do manually it will take more time for lot of attributes.

so Is there any sql query to rename attribute code.

ex:

```
current attribute code : "mp_local_shipping_charge"

need to be renamed as : "local"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic question, you can read more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198266/how-do-i-rename-an-attribute-code-in-magento

If you have lot of attributes, then you'd write a script based on the answer using `$installer`